# Why are there 3 ranges of private IPv4 addresses?

Tags: ip, ipv4, subnet, ip-address, rfc

Why are there three separate ranges of private IPv4 addresses of different sizes? Why not just reserve the largest (`10.0.0.0` - `10.255.255.255`) range and let people create `/16` or `/24` (or whatever) networks within that range if they need smaller networks or need to do subnetting? Is there anything wrong with having a huge number of available host addresses on your network?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Back when the RFC for private addressing was proposed, classful addressing was still common. The reasons for the three address ranges are found in [RFC 1918, Address Allocation for Private Internets](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918):

> If a suitable subnetting scheme can be designed and is supported by
> the equipment concerned, it is advisable to use the 24-bit block
> (class A network) of private address space and make an addressing plan
> with a good growth path. If subnetting is a problem, the 16-bit block
> (class C networks), or the 20-bit block (class B networks) of private
> address space can be used.

Comment: So there's no drawback at all if a cautious admin wants to use IP addresses in the 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 range (with a suitable subnetting scheme in case they want to create subnetworks in the future) even on very small networks?

Comment: Correct. Modern business networking equipment defaults to classless routing.

Answer (score 5):

While not an great answer (Ron Maupin's is more accurate), I was always taught to always use the the smallest class that left 10% room for expansion. This was "very important" with a facility that had many Subnets.

192.168.1.*
192.168.2.*
192.168.3.*

Could all be used to isolate entire security policies. For example the .1 network require the use of a proxy, .2 Maybe for management and bypass the proxy while .3 was the DMZ.

Some network equipment back then didn't even ask for a subnet. It just assumed you were using the entire class.

Eventually though that gave way to classless routing but it still is important to create segments that make easy sense.