# Addressing for a WAN, LAN and DMZ

Tags: ip, ipv4, ip-address, lan, wan

I was wondering about the addressing for certain types of networking areas...

I use 192.168.0.0 for a LAN network, 10.0.0.0 for a WAN and 172.16.0.0 for a DMZ. But I've been confused why a 10.0.0.0 is being used for a DMZ according to some sources I've found.

What are the purposes of using a 10.0.0.0(I understand this is a private network) address and a 172.16.0.0 address?

Is there a right or wrong of using a 10.0.0.0 address in a network?

Comment: You may also find the answer to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/32119/8499) useful.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Private addresses (RFC 1918) are

```
192.168.0.0/16
172.16.0.0/12
10.0.0.0/8
```

You can use any of these addresses in any combination that makes sense to you.  It doesn’t matter which one is DMZ, *etc.*

Also, to your computer or router, there is no difference between public and private addresses. IP addresses are just 32 bit numbers and computers treat them all the same.

Answer (score 1):

In the Internet addressing architecture, a private network is a network that uses private IP address space. These addresses are commonly used for local area networks in residential, office, and enterprise environments. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)

According to your requirement you can use any IP address range in your network. It is possible. Generally IP address range should select based on number of computers. It is does not matter which range or which class you have been using. But you should consider about subnet mask to define number of ip address.